# Compiler error while converting java Exception code to scala using intercept : ''forward reference extends over definition of value exception'

Tags: scala, scalatest

How to convert exception catching code from java to scala using intercept ?

From reading http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite it seems to be recommended to use intercept when catching exceptions. In the exception catching code below I need to access the Exception type so as to check its type within the 
assert :

```
catch {
          case me : MyException => {
            assert(me.getDetail.getClass() === classOf[GenericException]);
          }
        }
```

This does not seem to be possible using intercept as below code causes a compiler error : 'forward reference extends over definition of value exception'

Here is the converted to scala catch block :

```
        val exception = intercept[MyException] {
assert(exception.getDetail.getClass() === classOf[GenericException]);   
    }
```

The error occurs on line

```
assert(exception.getDetail.getClass() === classOf[GenericException]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your definition of `exception` is circular. What you want is:

```
val exception = intercept[MyException] {
   <your exception-throwing code here>
}

assert(exception.getDetail.getClass() === classOf[GenericException])
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. because code is being executed if an Exception is thrown, is this a closure or some other obstruct name ? I've never seen a val declared in this way

Comment: No it's just a normal method where your code block between the curly braces is the argument. Parens around the argument can be omitted if it's a code block, which allows you nice syntax like this. Take a look at the source for `intercept` if you want to understand further.